# how we stop or disable instant verification in firebase phone number authentication in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using phone number authentication using firebase. and I am facing issue in
Instant verification: in some cases the phone number can be instantly verified without needing to send or enter a verification code. How to disable or stop this process. Because I can use phone number verification with send message with code and after entered code verify the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You practicaly can't. If you need more documentation, go [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/296)

Comment: But I need for this . because in my app i am using phone number verification for verify account of signup. if sms is not send to the phone number then how we can verify the account .please help me.